# Shiro.ini ldap server credentials

Tags: apache, authentication, shiro

I'm using Apache Shiro plugin combined with LDAP for users authenticaion. To do it I need to keep LDAP server username and password. I really don't want to modify source code of the app and want to keep credentials in a config file shiro.ini
For now my shiro.ini looks like this

```
[main]
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.server.LdapGroupRealm
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase] = OU=Users,DC=mycompany,DC=local
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://myldapserver:389
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Users,dc=mycompany,dc=local
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = SIMPLE
securityManager.realms = $ldapRealm

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 86400000

shiro.loginUrl = /api/login
```

What would be a name of a property to do it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but I believe that it's binding *as* the user provided, rather than a separate user, which then looks up the DN of the user to authenticate against.  I just set up my zeppelin w/ ldap auth, and didn't have to put any 'bind user' into the config.

```
ldapRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.server.LdapGroupRealm
## search base for ldap groups (only relevant for LdapGroupRealm):
ldapRealm.contextFactory.environment[ldap.searchBase] = dc=mydomain,dc=local
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://ldap.mydomain.local:389
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=local
ldapRealm.contextFactory.authenticationMechanism = SIMPLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind to provide an example of your configuration?